# (How) can I see the edit history of questions in Area 51?

Tags: support, edits, area-51, revisions-list

Someone recently left a comment on an older Area 51 example question of mine. When reading the comment, I noticed that the question title was slightly different than I remembered it. Indeed, the [question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80273/website-recommendations/80295#80295) in question was edited by someone else about two months ago.

I don't mind that someone edited the question (*he probably improved it, because it's now a score-10 question*); I'm just curious about what the question used to say and what was changed. **Is there a way for me to see the edit history on Area 51 questions?**

(*I'm afraid to click to "rollback" button under the link, in case it changes the post and I can't change it back* :P)

Comment: I don't think it's possible. They weren't meant to be standalone questions anyway. Just, examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's a *UI* way (don't know why not - feature request?), but you can always modify the URL manually!

To do it, go to an example question, click `link` under it to get, in the address bar, for example:

> http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80273/website-recommendations/80295#80295

Get the number after the `#` (ie. `80295` in this case), and use the format:

> [site.com]/posts/[post-id]/revisions

to get the URL. So for this question:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/posts/80295/revisions

---

I've made a userscript to add a 'revisions' link to Area51 example questions.

### Get it at [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/shu8/306d9518e5fdb0dfe1ab).

[image]

See [here](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) if you're unsure on how to install userscripts.

Comment: Wow, so you can after all! Hmm, maybe they didn't want all the audience to see the revisions for some reason?

Comment: ...maybe, although I have no idea why - there must be *some* reason! In fact... I might just make a userscript to do this now...

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M most likely this is just a very old code (talking about 5 years old maybe more) that the team never bothered to update. Area 51 is using a separate code base that is not being updated.

Comment: @ShadowWizard possibly...probably...

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M made a userscript :)

Comment: I don't know if a [tag:feature-request] is worthwhile, since Area 52 is coming in 6-8.... /*shrugs/*